# Linq-to-sql code is not returning results even though the sql generated DOES return results

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have the following code in my application

```
var query = context.xosAssets.Where(x => x.GSA == 0).Take(INDEX_ASSET_QUERY_COUNT);
var assets = query.ToList();

// Debug
string message = string.Format("Assets waiting for indexing: {1}{0}Database:{3}{0}Query: {2}", 
    Environment.NewLine, query.Count(), query.ToString(), context.Connection.Database);
    System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("GSAFeed", message, System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information);
```

When this runs, `query.Count()` is zero and `assets.Count` is zero because no results are returned.  However, this is incorrect as ALL records in this database have their `GSA` field set to zero.

When I take the output from `query.ToString()` and run it (replacing `@p0` with 0), I get all the correct responses.  I have verified that I"m on the exact same database as is being outputted by `context.Connection.Database` and I am running out of options on what can be wrong.

Why is Linq-to-sql returning no results even though the actual sql does?

Comment: What is `INDEX_ASSET_QUERY_COUNT` set to?

Comment: `GSA` is a short, and `INDEX_ASSET_QUERY_COUNT` is a int const set at 250, which is correctly shown in the `TOP()` call in the outputted SQL.  *edit* eve nwithout the Top call it still fails.

Comment: Have you tried running SQL profiler and seeing what is actually being run on the database?

Comment: I actually just thought of that, but in the trace I"m not seeing any db requests for the tables i'm trying to hit, which doesn't make much sense

Comment: Are you building a new context/connection or reusing an existing one? If the latter, are you starting with an empty table and populating it either with a different context or using a non-linq method? If so Linq2Sql might be using cached results.

Comment: Just a minor note; you're evaluating query twice, once for setting `assets`, once for the `Count()`. The output line should really use assets.Count().

Comment: @sgmoore: I'm using a completely new context.  @Joachim: I did this only for debugging puprosesl.  I already knew `assets.Count` had zero elements, I wanted to make sure the query's count would also give me zero.

Comment: Can you be talking to a different server? you can use context.Connection.DataSource to check that.

Comment: Context.Connection.DataSource displays the same hostname as the computer name shows when RDP'ed to the db server

Comment: Well it decided to start working again with absolutely no code changes, thats irritating

Comment: That proves you are talking to correct windows server, but not necessarily to the same Sql server since it is possible for that windows server to be running two or more instances of sql. If you are using SQL Management Studio or Enterprise manager, do you refer to the server with the name alone?

Answer (score 0):

Ive ran into problems like this in the past, I generally re-write the Linq2Sql in long form & its gotten me out of trouble. Not expert enough to know why but it may help you.

**EDIT**
Something like this :

```
var query = (from x in context.xosAssets
            where x.GSA == 0
            select x).Take(INDEX_ASSET_QUERY_COUNT);
```

This should return IQueryable so no need to perform .ToLIst()

Comment: What do you mean in long form?